# Flutter geocode package throwing an error

Tags: flutter, geocode

I am using the geocode flutter package.

The below code was working before, but for a reason that I don't know it has stopped working and throwing the below error.

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception:
> FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1).

You have been blocked from the geocoder free xml port due to violation of ...
This is the code throwing the error:

```
await geoCode.reverseGeocoding(latitude: lat, longitude: long);
```

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you have been blocked for violating the terms of use of the geocoder, and your code is attempting to parse the error message in the response.

Comment: Thanks @DanHarms, the issue is I am not even seeing the rest of the comment to know which terms I might have violated

Comment: Check the response's status code. My hope is it is not a 200 and you will be able key off of that to know when to print the entire body string to logs.